# Open Firewall Port Programmatically in WinRT/Javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, client-server, server-side

I am developing a client/server Javascript Windows 8 Metro application. The user which operates the server instance can change the server port. I want to add a rule to firewall each time user changes the port, so he will not be confused because of a firewall issue, when clients can not connect to it. Even a way to check whether this port is accessible from outside is useful, so I can show the message to the user for adding the firewall rule.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall options you have a controlled by the [App capability declarations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx). If you specify the `internetClientServer` declaration then it will allow you to use any none-critical network port to listen on.

This might help also

> When an app attempts to listen for inbound unsolicited requests, the system will perform a check on the capabilities set for the app in its manifest and make a decision to allow or block the inbound unsolicited request from a remote IP address. An app must have either the InterentClientServer or the privateNetworkClientServer capability enabled to be allowed to listen for inbound unsolicited requests. If at least one of these capabilities is enabled, the app is allowed to listen on a port or several ports for inbound unsolicited requests on the specified network type. Every inbound unsolicited request attempt is checked to determine if an inbound unsolicited request from the specific remote source IP address is allowed. Windows determines whether the inbound unsolicited request is from a home\work IP address or the Internet and allows or denies access depending on the capabilities enabled and the specific remote address.

via http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770532.aspx

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.bindendpointasync.aspx) the connection will fail if the port is already open - I'm guessing that's what they mean when the talk about critical ports, but to be sure I'd avoid the standard ports (21,25,80,443,8080, etc)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ross Dargan, but let me be more clear about my question. Actually, I have no problem in opening the port in server. My problem arises after server starts its work by listening on the desired port, when clients try to connect to server. If there is a firewall on server, then users can not connect to it. I want to prevent this by opening the port programatically or by figuring out this state and tell user to add a proper firewall rule.